# How to connect C# with node.js via socket.io

Tags: c#, node.js, socket.io

i try to connect a c sharp application to node.js using SocketIoClientDotNet but it doesn't work take a look at my codes

```
using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client;
var socket = IO.Socket("http://localhost:7000");
socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
{
    socket.Emit("hi");
});
socket.On("hi", (data) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data);
        socket.Disconnect();
    });
Console.ReadLine()
```

And error is here

```
E:\xamp\htdocs\connexion>node test_server_2.js
   info  - socket.io started
   info  - unhandled socket.io url
```

Comment: are you on the latest versions of `socket.io` + `SocketIoClientDotNet` ?

Comment: my socket.io version is 0.9.16 and SocketioClientDotNet version is 0.9.10 do i upgrade socket.io ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found! i should upgrade socket.io from 0.9.16 to 1.3.5 and it works! thanks for all